# JQuery / Dojo click handling anomaly when HTML body is updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dojo, dom-events

I am  trying to install a mouse click handler on my web page programmaticly. 
The data handler function has a part that modifies the body like this:

```
document.body.innerHTML+='<div class=... id=...>X</div>'
```

After the addition, the click handler no long works and needs to be reconnected.
How can I solve this without reconnecting the function each time (some_condition) is true?

Here is my main.js (some lines omitted for clarity):

```
function parsenodes(data,ioargs){
    // IE does not supprt forEach method
    //data.forEach(function(item){
    dojo.forEach(data,function(item){
        //do something
        if(some_condifition)
            document.body.innerHTML+='<div class="some_class" id="unique_id">X</div>';
    });

}

var postData = function(){
    dojo.xhrPost({
        //url: "/ajax/get_messages",
        url: "/dbnode.json",
        handleAs: "json",
        load:parsenodes 
    });
};
function doUpdate()
{
    postData();
    setTimeout(doUpdate,1000);
}

function on_img_mb_down()
{
    alert("mouse clicked");
}

function init()
{
    console.debug("installing handler");
    //$('#resim').click(function() {alert("obarey")});
    handle = dojo.connect(dojo.byId("resim"),'onclick',on_img_mb_down);
    console.debug(handle);

    doUpdate();
}

dojo.ready(init);
//$(document).ready(init);
```

addendum: The anchor with id "resim" is a static HTML element:

```
<body>
    <a id="resim" style="border:1px;" ><img id="worldpng" src="world.png" /></a> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For updated question:*

When you change `.innerHTML` **all** of the elements in there are destroyed/recreated from the updated HTML, losing the `click` handlers, etc.  Instead of doing that, use DOM methods to append content, instead of this:

```
document.body.innerHTML+='<div class="some_class" id="unique_id">X</div>';
```

use something like this:

```
dojo.query("body").append("<div class="some_class" id="unique_id">X</div>");
```

---

*For previous question:*
You're only rigging up the handler when the on `ready` to elements that exist *then*, assuming you have the ID not repeated (which is a separate issue...if that's the case switch to a class), you just need to do:

```
dojo.connect(dojo.byId("resim"),'click',on_img_mb_down);
```

in your `parsenodes` method, after the load of new elements completes...because when they get replaced, their `click` handlers get destroyed, you need to re-create them on the new elements.

Comment: Also, the event name is `click`, not `clicked`.

Comment: @Justin - or `onclick`, but I assumed by the name he was firing a custom event here, I guess not...updating.

Comment: the ancher with id "resim" is a single, static HTML element, so that is not the issue. Or did I not get your point?

Comment: @Atilla - If that's not the case then your description of the problem is either incorrect or misleading, you said it *does* work if the ajax fails, e.g. no changes, correct?

Comment: @Nick: Yes that is correct. And yes, my description seems messing, update(or delete) will come soon.